# how to store multilevel JSON in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I want store JSON in powershell variable so that i can use them in Invoke-Request GET,POST,etc.

like below

```
$body = @{
 username = 'some username'
 password = 'some password'
}
$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

it gives me JSON like

```
{
 "username" : "some username"
 "password" : "some password"
}
```

But now i want to get output like below

```
  [
       {
          "op":"set",
          "member":"disks",
          "value":[
             {
               "diskId":"0:0",
               "sizeGB":1
             },
             {
               "diskId":"0:1",
               "sizeGB":2
             },
             {
               "diskId":"0:2",
               "sizeGB":16
             },
             {
               "path":"/extra",
               "sizeGB":"20",
               "type":"partitioned"
             }
          ]  
       }
    ]
```

how can i store this multilevel JSON in powershell variable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest hashtables and arrays in PowerShell. Here an example:

```
$body = @{
 'op' = 'set'
 'member' = 'disks'
 'value' = @(
    @{
        'diskId' = '0:0'
        'sizeGB' = '1'
    }, 
    @{
        'diskId' = '0:1'
        'sizeGB' = '2'
    }
    @{
        'diskId' = '0:2'
        'sizeGB' = '16'
    }
    @{
        'path' = '/extra'
        'sizeGB' = '20'
        'type' = 'partitioned'
    }
 )
}
```

Note that `value`is an Array (using `@()`) of hashtables.

Comment: i converted it to JSON using ConvertTo-JSON call but converted JSON failed to parse

Comment: {
    "op":  "set", "value":  [                  {
                      "sizeGB":  "1",
                      "diskId":  "0:0"
                  },
                  {
                      "sizeGB":  "2",
                      "diskId":  "0:1"
                  },
                  {
                      "sizeGB":  "16",
                      "diskId":  "0:2"
                  },
                  {
                      "path:":  "/extra",
                      "sizeGB":  "20",
                      "type":  "partitioned"
                  }
              ],
    "member":  "disk"
}

Comment: above is the JSON converted from your solution

Comment: expected is [
   {
      "op":"set",
      "member":"disks",
      "value":[
         {
           "diskId":"0:0",
           "sizeGB":1
         },
         {
           "diskId":"0:1",
           "sizeGB":2
         },
         {
           "diskId":"0:2",
           "sizeGB":16
         },
         {
           "path":"/extra",
           "sizeGB":"20",
           "type":"partitioned"
         }
      ]  
   }
]

Comment: The output is valid JSON (checked with Json validator). The `[`brackets are generated if you have an array of these settings

Comment: thanks jisaak, How can i get it like exact  above expected.

Comment: Why do you want that? You already have valid Json! If you have to, you could use something like `'[{0}]' -f $body | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Actually i am sending request to cloud with REST api and it is expected JSON format above in documentaion and its failing with error "An error occured while deserializing the request JSON content."

Comment: ah, maybe because i have `:`in path and wrote `disk`instead of `disks`. I updated my answer, try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86703/discussion-between-dipak-and-jisaak).